# What are options to unit test requestAnimationFrame in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, zone.js, ngzone

What are ways to unit test requestAnimationFrame?

requestAnimationFrame has same nature as setTimeout/setInterval have. It is also patched by zone.js like fn's like setTimeout are patched. So options which first came to my mind are

1. async + whenStable
2. fakeAsync + tick(void)
3. fakeAsync + flush
4. fakeAsync + tick(number)
5. setTimeout(1000) + done (jasmine)

The results:

1. async + whenStable : just don't work
2. fakeAsync + tick(void) : don't work
3. fakeAsync + flush : don't work
4. fakeAsync + tick(number) : works (read below)
5. setTimeout(1000) + done (jasmine) : don't work

Here is the method:

```
 reqAnimFrame() {
   requestAnimationFrame(() => {
     console.log('log stuff');
     this.title = 'req frame title';
   });
 }
```

Here is the unit test (working unit test):

```
it('fakeAsync', fakeAsync(function () {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app: AppComponent = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;

  fixture.detectChanges();

  app.reqAnimFrame();

  tick(16);

  expect(app.title).toBe('req frame title');
}));
```

Magic number. 16 is some magic number like 1000/60. It is the frame size. I just found this magic number by experiments.

Also, idea which came to my mind when I was writing this question: probably, I can somehow mock ng zone and all code which passes through it will be called synchronously (I need that). I haven't tried this yet.

UPD: After some research RAF call just put a task into macrotask zone queue. How to flush this queue from the test?

So what I am missing? How to correctly unit test method with `requestAnimationFrame` call?

Comment: It is not opinion based at all. I am asking for the ways of testing specific stuff.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12372. Ta-daaa.

Answer (score 8):

`tick(16)` is correct, because `requestAnimationFrame` in `fakeAsync` is just a `16ms delay macroTask`.

if you want to flush in `fakeAsync`, just call `flush()`, flush is also imported from `@angular/core/testing`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I said that in my question. Btw I am that guy   sharikovvladislav from github :) We talked a bit in issue.

Comment: OK, could you provide a reproduce repo in github, I will fix it if it is a bug.